# After submitting a form and redirecting back to the same page, how can I prevent the browser's back button from simply reloading the same page again?

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

Page 1 is the homepage.

Page 2 is a forum discussion.

Page 3 is comment submission back-end code.

If a user goes from the homepage (page 1) to the discussion page (page 2) and then submits a comment, page 3 is used to insert the comment into the database and then redirect the user (using a header redirect) back to the discussion (page 2). Now if the user clicks the browser's back button, it takes them to the earlier version of page 2, when in fact I want them to go back to the homepage (page 1).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You might want to manipulate the browser history stack: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Does this only happen in firefox?

Comment: No. I'm testing in chrome.